# How to configure internet on old linux VM

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, network-interface, internet

I have downloaded the first version of Mendrake running kernel 2.0.35 for study purposes. I installed the system on a virtual machine (VirtualBox), i used SCSI virtual hard drive for compatibility & did everything But the only thing i couldn't get to run is Internet.
 VirtualBox's adapter is attached to NAT (Virtual machine gets connected as soon as host OS is connected), i usually get an IP address on eth0 interface but now on this Mendrake VM, eth0 doesn't seem to come up when i list network interfaces using `ifconfig`.
 So i need a way to setup eth0 & get Internet connectivity on Mendrake VM (If there's other possibilities or other configurations, it's ok to test them, because all i need is the Internet working).

I'll use internet to download GCC & GDB packges that are needed for my studies.
If there's a way how to download those packages on host OS & then send them to VM, i'll be glad to know it.
Host OS:Debian x86
Running lspci on host OS:

```
root@afr0ck:~# lspci | grep -i "Ethernet"
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
```

Comment: @Anthon It's really hard to configure shared folder using a 1998 linux without having a graphical interface, please can you provide me some readings about the subject, thanks in advance.

Comment: As you need to install the guest additions, on second thought, shared folders might not be a feasible path.

Comment: As virtualbox presents a virtual network card to the vm, the `lspci` output from the host doesn't matter. I have no idea if kernel 2.0.35 supports any of the network cards virtualbox can present, but you can try ro see if it helps to choose another one.

Comment: The PCnet-PCI II (Am79C970A) looks like the best bet from the list of devices offered by virtualbox. There is a pcnet32 driver in 2.0.35 as you can see in the [kernel config](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/tree/drivers/net/Config.in?h=2.0.35#n77) and the model number 79C970A is [specifically mentioned in `pcnet.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/tree/drivers/net/pcnet32.c?h=2.0.35#n181)

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I made that choice, i reinstalled the system & when setting up network card, the installer doesn't show me card driver for AMD PCnet-PCI II. Can i set it up manually ?

Comment: You can start with `modprobe pcnet32` to see if the driver is included in the distribution. Maybe even `insmod pcnet32`; I know we used to use `insmod` a lot more than we do now.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley the output of `insmod pcnet32` claims that a module named pcnet32 already exists. What to do next ?

Comment: Run `lspci` inside the virtualbox? Check `dmesg` output (or look for a kernel log in `/var/log`) for messages from the pcnet32 driver? And do you know the difference between `ifconfig` and `ifconfig -a`? Maybe it's been there the whole time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issues with getting the Ethernet adapter to show are likely a lack of drivers in the older kernel that would support the virtual NIC that VirtualBox presents.

However, a quick way to get the files onto the VM would be to download them to the host machine, burn them to a CD, attach that CD to the VM via VirtualBox, then mount it within the VM. If you don't have an optical drive on the host machine you can use a program like [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/create-iso-file.htm) to create an ISO that can then be attached as if it were a physical CD.

Comment: Mounting the ISO was a very practical idea. I have successfully installed the packages (Although Internet connectivity problems remains unsolved) .